# Platform-specific audio lag with VideoPlayer when Pausing and Playing in Unity on Mac

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, video

I'm working on a Unity adaptation of a Samuel Beckett play - running Unity 2018.3.4f1 and coding in C#.

I've got a video of the play and the script of the play; as the player types the lines of the script, the video plays the words they've typed. The script of the play includes the timestamps for the end of each line as they appear in the video; when the user finishes typing a given line, a float PlayUntil is incremented so it equals the timestamp of the end of the line. PlayUntil is checked against videoController.currentTime in a FixedUpdate(); if the video is further advanced than PlayUntil, it pauses the video.

This works fine on my Windows computer, both in the editor and on builds. However, when I attempt to play it on my Mac - either in the editor or in a built version - there's substantial audio lag. More specifically, the first quarter of a second or so of audio from the video is cut off every time it starts playing again after having been paused.

I've tried transcoding the video file, both through Unity and through VLC, to a variety of different audio formats (AAC, mp3, etc); no obvious change there. My hacked solution is to rewind the video every time I start playing again, but this is janky as hell. Is there any way to reduce the audio cutoff when a video played via VideoPlayer on a Mac pauses and plays?

VideoController.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;


public class VideoController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public VideoPlayer video;
    public Slider slider;
    public float PlayUntil = 0.0f;
    public float timePaused = 0f;
    public float startTime;
//properties of the video player
bool isDone;

public float getTimePaused
{
    get { return timePaused; }
}
public bool IsPlaying
{
    get { return video.isPlaying; }
}

public bool IsPrepared
{
    get { return video.isPrepared; }
}

public bool IsDone
{
    get { return isDone;  }
}

public double currentTime
{
    get { return video.time; }
}

public ulong Duration
{
    get { return (ulong)(video.frameCount / video.frameRate); }
}


void OnEnable()
{
    video.errorReceived += errorReceived;
    video.frameReady += frameReady;
    video.prepareCompleted += prepareCompleted;
    video.seekCompleted += seekCompleted;
    video.started += started;
    video.time = 0.1f;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    video.errorReceived -= errorReceived;
    video.frameReady -= frameReady;
    video.prepareCompleted -= prepareCompleted;
    video.seekCompleted -= seekCompleted;
    video.started -= started;
}

void errorReceived(VideoPlayer v, string msg)
{
    Debug.Log("video player error: " + msg);
}

void frameReady(VideoPlayer v, long frame)
{

}

void prepareCompleted(VideoPlayer v)
{
    Debug.Log("video player finished prepping");
    isDone = false;
}

void seekCompleted(VideoPlayer v)
{
    Debug.Log("video player finished seeking");
    isDone = false;
}

void started(VideoPlayer v)
{
   //  Debug.Log("video player started");
}

private void Start()
{
    video.Prepare();
    Application.targetFrameRate = 20;
    video.targetCameraAlpha = 0.1f;
    video.time = 0.1f;
}

public void LoadVideo()
{
    string temp = Application.dataPath + "/Video/" + "NotI.mp4";
    if (video.url == temp) return;
    video.url = temp;
    video.Prepare();
    Debug.Log("can set direct audio volume: " + video.canSetDirectAudioVolume);
    Debug.Log("can set playback speed: " + video.canSetPlaybackSpeed);
    Debug.Log("can set time: " + video.canSetTime);
    Debug.Log("can step: " + video.canStep);
}

public void PlayVideo()
{
    if (!IsPrepared) return;
    if (IsPlaying) return;
    video.Play();
    timePaused += Time.time - startTime;
    startTime = 0f;

}

public void PauseVideo()
{
    if (!IsPlaying) return;
    video.Pause();
    startTime = Time.time;

}

public void Seek(float time)
{
    if (!video.canSetTime) return;
    if (!IsPrepared) return;
    video.time = time;
}

public void SetPlaybackSpeed(float speed)
{
    if (!video.canSetPlaybackSpeed) return;
    video.playbackSpeed = speed;
}

public void IncrementPlaybackSpeed()
{
    if (!video.canSetPlaybackSpeed) return;

    video.playbackSpeed += 1;
}

public void DecrementPlaybackSpeed()
{
    if (!video.canSetPlaybackSpeed) return;

    video.playbackSpeed -= 1;
}

}
```

~~

and WordManager.cs, which handles timing:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class WordManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Word> words;
    public List<Word> settings;
    // Make the main list:

    // Use the test w/ timestamps
    public TextAsset ATTTScript;

    //public static string cleanText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Assets/Text/AlmostToTheTickScript.txt", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    //public static string[] listOfWords = cleanText.Split('\n');
    public static string cleanText;
    public static string[] listOfWords;
    public VideoController videoController;
    public WordSpawner wordSpawner;
    private static float offset = 0f;
    private bool hasActiveWord;
    private Word activeWord;
    public static int position = 0;
    public string currentWord;
    public float currentTime;
    // if you're using an offset:


    // variables for settings
    public static Vector3 settingsLocation = new Vector3(-4.0f, -1f);
    public static bool timerShowing = false;
    public static bool wpmShowing;
    public static bool accuracyShowing;
    public static bool pauseTimerShowing = false;
    public static bool progressShowing = false;
    public static string settingsString;
    public static float speedFactor = 1f;
    private float PlayUntil = 0.00f;
    private Vector3 defaultLocation = new Vector3(0f, 2.5f, 0f);
    private Vector3 secondLocation = new Vector3(0f, 2.0f, 0f);

    private void Start()
    {
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer)
        {
            offset = -.15f;
        }
        cleanText = ATTTScript.ToString();
        listOfWords = cleanText.Split('\n');
        currentWord = listOfWords[position].Split('_')[0];
        currentTime = float.Parse(listOfWords[position].Split('_')[1]) + offset;
        GameObject InfoBox = GameObject.Find("InfoBox");
        if (GameObject.Find("InfoBox") != null)
        {
            InfoBoxScript info = InfoBox.GetComponent<InfoBoxScript>();
            speedFactor = info.getSpeed();
            Debug.Log("Playing at " + speedFactor + "speed");
            Debug.Log("StatsOn = " + info.getStatsOn());
            if (info.getStatsOn())
            {
                timerShowing = true;
                pauseTimerShowing = true;
                progressShowing = true;
            }
        }
        settingsString = makeSettingsString();
        Word settingsWord = new Word("settings", 9999f, wordSpawner.SpawnWord(settingsLocation));
        settingsWord.ChangeSize(14);
        settingsWord.ChangeAlign("Upper Left");
        settingsWord.ChangeWord(settingsString);
        settings.Add(settingsWord);
        AddWord();
        AddWord();
        videoController.SetPlaybackSpeed(speedFactor);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //settings stuff
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            timerShowing = !timerShowing;
            pauseTimerShowing = !pauseTimerShowing;
            progressShowing = !progressShowing;
        }
        settingsString = makeSettingsString();
        settings[0].ChangeWord(settingsString);

        if (!videoController.IsPrepared)
        {
            // Debug.Log("Not ready!");
            return;
        }
        if (videoController.currentTime < PlayUntil)
        {
            // Debug.Log(video.time + " < " + PlayUntil);
            videoController.PlayVideo();
        }
        else
        {
            // Debug.Log(video.time + " > " + PlayUntil);
            videoController.PauseVideo();
        }
        if (words[0].GetVector3() != defaultLocation)
        {
            words[0].MoveTowards(defaultLocation);
        }
    }
    public void AddWord()
    {
        Vector3 newWordLocation = defaultLocation;
        Word lastWord = null;
        if (words.Count == 0)
        {
            newWordLocation = defaultLocation;
        }
        else
        {
            newWordLocation = secondLocation;
        }

        if (position > listOfWords.Length - 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Done");
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
        }
        currentWord = listOfWords[position].Split('_')[0];
        currentTime = float.Parse(listOfWords[position].Split('_')[1]) + offset;
        Word word = new Word(currentWord, currentTime, wordSpawner.SpawnWord(newWordLocation), lastWord);
        Debug.Log(currentWord);
        words.Add(word);
        position = position + 1;       
    }

    public void TypeLetter(char letter)
    {
        if (hasActiveWord)
        {
            if (activeWord.GetNextLetter() == letter)
            {
                activeWord.TypeLetter();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (words[0].GetNextLetter() == letter)
            {
                activeWord = words[0];
                hasActiveWord = true;
                words[0].TypeLetter();
            }
        }

        if (hasActiveWord && activeWord.WordTyped())
        {
            hasActiveWord = false;
            PlayUntil = activeWord.GetEndTime();
            words.Remove(activeWord);
            AddWord();
        }
        // ` = skip mode.
        if (hasActiveWord && letter == '`')
        {
            hasActiveWord = false;
            PlayUntil = activeWord.GetEndTime();
            words.Remove(activeWord);
            activeWord.RemoveWord();
            AddWord();
        }
        else if(!hasActiveWord && letter == '`')
        {
            activeWord = words[0];
            hasActiveWord = true;
            words[0].TypeLetter();
        }
    }

    private string makeSettingsString()
    {
        settingsString = "";
        if (timerShowing)
        {
            float videoTime = Mathf.Round((float)videoController.currentTime * 100.0f) / 100f;
            settingsString += "Video Time: " + videoTime + "\n";
        }
        if(pauseTimerShowing)
        {
            float timePaused = Mathf.Round(videoController.getTimePaused*100f)/100f;
            settingsString += "Time spent paused: " + timePaused + "\n";
        }
        if (progressShowing)
        {
            settingsString += "At position " + (position-2) + " of " + listOfWords.Length + "\n";
        }
        return settingsString;
    }
}
```